# How can I correct this error from testing of my mask rcnn model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, faster-rcnn

[image]

Please I need solution with correcting and running this code for mask rcnn

Comment: Do not post images of code, post the code instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Gtomika, please provide error trace in text format. Also provide more details about the repo where you got the model from and any other information that you think is relevant.

Based on my past experience, I'm pretty sure that you are using Matterplot's mask RCNN and your issue is due to class count mismatch. You are trying to load weight of a model that was trained on a different class count. You should exclude some layers such as 'mrcnn_bbox_fc','mrcnn_class_logits’.

Fix is to change `model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)` to `model.load_weights(filepath, by_name=True, exclude=[ "mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc", "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"])`

Refer [this issue](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/849) for more information.